# Can't click links in lower z-index element in Chrome/Firefox/Safari

Tags: html, css

This code works fine in internet explorer, but I am having problems in other browsers. 
Basically there is a horizontally scrolling page with a fixed left sidebar.
In IE you can click on the forward and back buttons on each panel of the page, but in chrome, etc, only the links in the sidebar work.
I believe it to be a problem with the z-index or positioning of the elements, the css has

```
#bg{
   display:inline;
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:-2px;
   z-index:1;
}

#sidestripe {
   display:inline;
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   top:-2px;
   width:100%;
   min-height: 100%;
   z-index:1000;
}
```

I have tried many combinations of z-index, but i can't seem to make one elemnt clickable without making the other unclickable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://www.travelhome.com.au/index.htm is the website in question

Comment: the highest level element is a sidestripe only covering a portion of the page, so i guess this would be true... do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you need `#sidestripe` be `width:100%` when it can be `width:380px` and it would not then cover any part of the content

Comment: thanks! that worked, its all fixed now :)

Comment: Thanks so much for your speedy responses while the boss was looking over my shoulder ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `#sidestripe` width to `380px` instead of `100%`:

```
#sidestripe {
display:inline;
position:fixed;
left:0px;
top:-2px;
width:380px;
min-height: 100%;
z-index:1000;
}
```

This way it will not cover other content on the page

Comment: would this mean that i wouldn't then be able to click links in the higher level items?

Comment: yes, it would definitely mean that. Basically, any mouse events would not apply to the higher element anymore (not only click)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what can be exactly the problem but I had a similar problem some time ago.

To fix it I navigated through the developer tool of Google Chrome and a predefined Z-index was applied by a hidden class, so mine was being overwritten.

Try to find all the classes applied and possibly you will find something similar.

This usually happens when working with APIs.